# how to search for file's has a known file extension like .py?

Tags: python, file, search

how to search for file's has a known file extension like .py ??

```
fext = raw_input("Put file extension to search: ")
dir = raw_input("Dir to search in: ")

##Search for the file and get the right one's
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-recursive:

```
for x in os.listdir(dir):
    if x.endswith(fext):
        filename = os.path.join(dir, x)
        # do your stuff here
```

Comment: Do we need `os.path.join`? I guess `x` itself is `filename`.

Comment: x is only the filename without the directory name, at least in python 2.5 and python 2.6 IIRC

Comment: This has a bug—it catches `.epy` files when you are looking for `.py` files. Also, `glob.glob` is the right tool for this job.

Comment: Mike: it won't catch `.epy` files when looking for `.py` files. It will when looking for `py` files.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want to do something like similar to this: `/dir/to/search/*.extension`?

This is called glob and here is how to use it:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('/path/*.extension')
```

Edit: and here is the documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html

Comment: There is no reason for this not to work. From the docs "This is done by using the os.listdir() and fnmatch.fnmatch() functions in concert, and not by actually invoking a subshell". (I also believe that this is the correct solution to your problem, one should prefer built-in functionality before creating ones own.)

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
root="/home"
ext = raw_input("Put file extension to search: ")
path = raw_input("Dir to search in: ")
for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
    for files in f:
         if files.endswith(ext):
              print "found: ",os.path.join(r,files)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write is as simple as:

```
import os
ext = raw_input("Put file extension to search: ")
path = raw_input("Dir to search in: ")
matching_files = [os.path.join(path, x) for x in os.listdir(path) if x.endswith(ext)]
```